# A book for learning Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

Since I've just started to use Ubuntu, can you recommend me a good book or anything very useful in pdf format? I have version 18.04, and I would not want to constantly search everywhere on the Internet whenever I have troubles with commands, settings, instructions and stuff like that, but that the most important be in one place, like a good guidelines?

Thanks :)

Comment: Many books are outdated fast. I suggest you use online resources,  start with the ubuntu documentation and branch out as needed. Other distros maintain documentation as well, arch and RHEL / Fedora and most but not all applies to Ubuntu as well

Comment: We are an online based OS so we do things online. Books get dusty quickly with 6 monht releases. Good Google-fu is what you need :)

Comment: Be sure to bookmark this: https://www.explainshell.com/  :)

Comment: @Rinzwind that is amazing, very helpful, thank you :)

Comment: @Panther okay, I'll try to get used to online resources

Comment: Linux is a different kind of OS, and it really is more of an amalgam of many different things, many of which have little to do with the distro (e.g. Ubuntu). For instance, if you want to know how to filter a list, change permissions, run commands, then for the most part you're looking for a guide to the unix terminal. If you're trying to install a program from the terminal, then you're really looking for how to install a program in Debian (Ubuntu's "family"). Thus, in short, I'd recommend looking for guides on using Linux, and only get specific to Ubuntu when it matters (it's usually obvious).

Answer (score 10):

You can see an online manual below:

[Ubuntu Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html)

and from the same site [here](https://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads), you can download a pdf (at the moment) for 16.04 (and other versions) but I'm sure before long there will be a pdf for version 18.04.n and whilst there will inevitably be some differences between versions 16 and 18, this should provide you with a reasonable grounding in the basics until the v 18 resource is made available.

Comment: I only see PDF downloads for Ubuntu Server.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Apologies, edit the URL to the following: https://help.ubuntu.com/ and you will see the other links...

Comment: That link still only hosts links to HTML versions of the *Desktop* version.

Comment: @NonnyMoose further research reveals: https://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads.